# Catching pokemon "Bonus" XP

Tags: pokemon-go

I did not use any Lucky Egg, also as you can see in photo below, there is already an additional 50XP from "Great Throw" then I'm surprised that I received a "Bonus" exp from catching a Magikarp.
I tried catching other pokemon again, and there was none.

[image]

**Where did this "Bonus" exp came from?**

Answer (score 1):

This bonus is awarded on each 100th of that Pokémon caught. [Source](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/077d6dea82d58b8febde54ae9729b1bf#file-game_master_v0_1-protobuf-L258)

Comment: Is there a source for that? I've seen a couple of bonus posts, one for a venonat (which I have *definitely* not caught 100 of)

Comment: Besides personal experience, this is the source linked on the possible duplicate question: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/077d6dea82d58b8febde54ae9729b1bf#file-game_master_v0_1-protobuf-L258 (Line 258)

Comment: Thanks. Can't view it at work, but the linked answer is pretty detailed. Might want to edit that source into this answer though :)